# How to relate xib to storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I build an app with storyboard I need 356 viewcontroller at storyboard that's a lot and it is not possible to work with so many screens I create tab bar and table cell at storyboard I create xib I want do relationship from xib to table cell at storyboard how do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Whoa - run-on sentence much. Learn to use periods ('.'s). I would edit, but I honestly can't tell what you're trying to say. Please fix your grammar.

Comment: I would be very, very surprised if you actually needed hundreds of view controllers.  Can you give a bit of background about what it is you are doing?

Comment: This my project sendspace.com/file/9186fm and sorry for my English (The language the project is Hebrew)

Answer (score 0):

You have too many view controllers but Ill humour the actual question:

```
UIStoryBoard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];

BrowserViewController *vc = (BrowserViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BrowserViewController"];

//get whatever instance you want off the VCs properties a table view or whatever
// but usually youll just want to push it onto a nav controller

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wire from TableViewController to other view.

[image: ss]

For example, at first, you can set TableViewCell as below:

[image: ss]

When tap the cell, the view with the number of tapped cell.

[image: ss]

To send the number of tapped cell to next ViewController, you can use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and `prepareForSegue:sender` as below.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" 
                              sender:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row + 1]];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DetailViewController *c = segue.destinationViewController;
    c.string = (NSString *)sender;
}
```

You can download this project and just run it.

https://github.com/weed/p120809_TableCellToView

Comment: This my project http://www.sendspace.com/file/9186fm now I need 365 view controller (The language is Hebrew)

Comment: Is this a book? I suppose you want to make e-book with 365 pages, every page has its own contents. I suggest you make not 365 ViewControllers but 365 images. You can change the image as which cell tapped. How about this ?

Comment: It's not book it's  tip for day each day a different tip I need 365 row in table view cell date written on each row with search date and once you click it puts a tip and navigation controller to back for tableview

Comment: I think you have to write code to change ViewController to behave different ways. I expect your fight.